# TypeError: webpackMerge.strategy is not a function

Tags: angular, webpack, dependencies

I'm currently upgrading an old angular project to latest Angular version. I'm facing this issue when I try to build and I don't really understand why it's happenning.

Here is the error message that I got:

```
[webpack-cli] Failed to load '...\config\webpack.dev.js' config
[webpack-cli] TypeError: webpackMerge.strategy is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (...\config\webpack.dev.js:3:38)
    at Module._compile (...\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (...\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at WebpackCLI.tryRequireThenImport (...\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:245:16)
    at loadConfigByPath (...\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:1725:30)
    at ...\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:1780:11

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.22621
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "...\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "webpack" "--" "--config" "config/webpack.dev.js"
npm ERR! node v14.20.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! projectmonitor@0.0.1 webpack: `webpack --progress "--config" "config/webpack.dev.js"`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the project webpack script 'webpack --progress "--config" "config/webpack.dev.js"'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the project package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     webpack --progress "--config" "config/webpack.dev.js"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs project
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls project
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     ...\npm-debug.log
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "build_number": "${build_number}",
  "description": "Project",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "15.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "15.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "15.2.2",
    "@angular/animations": "15.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "15.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "15.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "15.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "15.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "15.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "15.2.2",
    "@angularclass/conventions-loader": "1.0.13",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "3.0.0",
    "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "3.0.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "14.0.1",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "15.2.2",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "15.2.0",
    "amcharts3": "github:amcharts/amcharts3",
    "ammap3": "github:amcharts/ammap3",
    "animate.css": "4.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "5.2.3",
    "chart.js": "1.1.1",
    "chartist": "0.10.1",
    "ckeditor": "4.6.2",
    "core-js": "3.29.0",
    "easy-pie-chart": "2.1.7",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "fullcalendar": "3.3.1",
    "google-maps": "3.2.1",
    "http-server": "0.9.0",
    "ie-shim": "0.1.0",
    "ionicons": "2.0.1",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "jquery-confirm": "^3.3.4",
    "jquery-slimscroll": "1.3.8",
    "jquery-toast-plugin": "^1.3.1",
    "leaflet": "0.7.7",
    "leaflet-map": "0.2.1",
    "lodash": "4.17.21",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "1.3.7",
    "ng2-completer": "9.0.1",
    "ng2-order-pipe": "0.1.5",
    "ng2-smart-table": "1.7.2",
    "ng2-tree": "2.0.0-rc.11",
    "ngx-cookie": "4.1.2",
    "ngx-uploader": "11.0.0",
    "normalize.css": "8.0.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.13",
    "roboto-fontface": "0.10.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "tether": "2.0.0",
    "tsickle": "^0.46.3",
    "webpack": "5.76.0",
    "webpack-cli": "4.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "1.10.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "4.9.0",
    "webpack-dll-bundles-plugin": "1.0.0-beta.5",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "webpack-serve": "^4.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.0",
    "@angular/cli": "15.2.2",
    "@types/fullcalendar": "3.8.0",
    "@types/hammerjs": "2.0.34",
    "@types/handlebars": "4.0.33",
    "@types/jquery": "2.0.41",
    "@types/uglify-js": "2.6.28",
    "@types/webpack": "2.2.14",
    "add-asset-html-webpack-plugin": "1.0.2",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "3.5.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.1.2",
    "bootstrap-loader": "4.0.4",
    "codelyzer": "6.0.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.0",
    "es6-promise": "4.1.0",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "es7-reflect-metadata": "1.6.0",
    "exports-loader": "0.6.4",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.1",
    "find-root": "1.0.0",
    "font-awesome-sass-loader": "2.0.1",
    "gh-pages": "0.12.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^5.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.28.0",
    "imports-loader": "0.7.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "ng-router-loader": "2.1.0",
    "ngc-webpack": "4.1.2",
    "node-sass": "^8.0.0",
    "npm-run-all": "4.0.2",
    "optimize-js-plugin": "0.0.4",
    "postcss-loader": "1.3.3",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "2.0.2",
    "rimraf": "2.6.1",
    "sass-loader": "7.3.1",
    "script-ext-html-webpack-plugin": "1.7.1",
    "source-map-loader": "0.2.1",
    "string-replace-loader": "1.2.0",
    "style-loader": "0.16.1",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "ts-node": "3.0.2",
    "tslint": "5.0.0",
    "typedoc": "0.5.10",
    "typescript": "4.8.4",
    "typogr": "0.6.6",
    "underscore": "1.8.3",
    "url-loader": "0.5.8",
    "webpack": "5.76.0",
    "webpack-cli": "4.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "1.10.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "4.9.0",
    "webpack-dll-bundles-plugin": "1.0.0-beta.5",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "webpack-serve": "^4.0.0",
    "wintersmith": "2.3.6",
    "wintersmith-sassy": "1.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "rimraf": "rimraf",
    "tslint": "tslint",
    "typedoc": "typedoc",
    "webpack": "webpack --progress",
    "webpack-dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
    "webdriver-manager": "webdriver-manager",
    "clean": "npm cache clean && npm run rimraf -- node_modules doc coverage dist compiled dll",
    "clean:dist": "npm run rimraf -- dist",
    "clean:dll": "npm run rimraf -- dll",
    "preclean:install": "npm run clean",
    "clean:install": "npm set progress=false && npm install",
    "preclean:start": "npm run clean",
    "clean:start": "npm start",
    "watch": "npm run watch:dev",
    "watch:dev": "npm run build:dev",
    "watch:dev:hmr": "npm run watch:dev -- --hot",
    "watch:prod": "npm run build:prod",
    "build": "npm run build:dev",
    "prebuild:dev": "npm run clean:dist",
    "build:dev": " npm run clean:dist && npm run webpack -- --config config/webpack.dev.js",
    "prebuild:prod": "npm run clean:dist",
    "build:prod": "npm run clean:dist && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js  --progress --profile",
    "server": "npm run server:dev",
    "server:dev": "webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --content-base src/",
    "server:dev:hmr": "npm run server:dev -- --inline --hot",
    "server:prod": "http-server dist -c-1 --cors",
    "server:test": "http-server dist-demo -c-1 --cors",
    "server:prod:ci": "http-server dist -p 3000 -c-1 --cors",
    "webdriver:update": "npm run webdriver-manager update",
    "webdriver:start": "npm run webdriver-manager start",
    "lint": "npm run tslint \"src/**/*.ts\" --force",
    "ngc": "./node_modules/.bin/ngc-w -p tsconfig.webpack.json",
    "pree2e": "npm run webdriver:update -- --standalone",
    "pretest": "npm run lint",
    "docs": "npm run typedoc -- --options typedoc.json --exclude '**/*.spec.ts' ./src/",
    "gh-pages": "wintersmith build -C docs && gh-pages -d docs/build",
    "start": "npm run server:dev",
    "start:hmr": "npm run server:dev:hmr",
    "version": "npm run build",
    "postversion": "git push && git push --tags",
    "build:aot:prod": "npm run clean:dist && npm run clean:aot && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js  --progress --profile --bail",
    "build:aot": "npm run build:aot:prod",
    "clean:aot": "npm run rimraf -- compiled",
    "build:ci": "npm run build:prod && npm run build:aot"
  }
}
```

and here is my webpack file that seems to be the problem:

```
const helpers = import('./helpers');
const webpackMerge = import('webpack-merge'); // used to merge webpack configs
const webpackMergeDll = webpackMerge.strategy({plugins: 'replace'});
const commonConfig = import('./webpack.common.js'); // the settings that are common to prod and dev

const AddAssetHtmlPlugin = import('add-asset-html-webpack-plugin');
const DefinePlugin = import('webpack/lib/DefinePlugin');
const LoaderOptionsPlugin = import('webpack/lib/LoaderOptionsPlugin');

const ENV = process.env.ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';
const HOST = process.env.HOST || 'localhost';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const HMR = helpers.hasProcessFlag('hot');
const METADATA = webpackMerge(commonConfig({env: ENV}).metadata, {
  host: HOST,
  port: PORT,
  ENV: ENV,
  HMR: HMR
});

const DllBundlesPlugin = require('webpack-dll-bundles-plugin').DllBundlesPlugin;

module.exports = function (options) {
  return webpackMerge(commonConfig({env: ENV}), {

    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',

    output: {

      path: helpers.root('dist'),

      filename: '[name].bundle.js',

      sourceMapFilename: '[file].map',

      chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js',

      library: 'ac_[name]',
      libraryTarget: 'var',
    },

    plugins: [
      // NOTE: when adding more properties, make sure you include them in custom-typings.d.ts
      new DefinePlugin({
        'ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
        'HMR': METADATA.HMR,
        'process.env': {
          'ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
          'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
          'HMR': METADATA.HMR,
        }
      }),

      new DllBundlesPlugin({
        bundles: {
          polyfills: [
            'core-js',
            {
              name: 'zone.js',
              path: 'zone.js/dist/zone.js'
            },
            {
              name: 'zone.js',
              path: 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js'
            },
            'ts-helpers',
          ],
          vendor: [
            '@angular/platform-browser',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
            '@angular/core',
            '@angular/common',
            '@angular/forms',
            '@angular/common/http',
            '@angular/router',
            '@angularclass/hmr',
            'rxjs',
          ]
        },
        dllDir: helpers.root('dll'),
        webpackConfig: webpackMergeDll(commonConfig({env: ENV}), {
          devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
          plugins: []
        })
      }),

      new AddAssetHtmlPlugin([
        { filepath: helpers.root(`dll/${DllBundlesPlugin.resolveFile('polyfills')}`) },
        { filepath: helpers.root(`dll/${DllBundlesPlugin.resolveFile('vendor')}`) }
      ]),


      new LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        debug: true,
        options: {
          context: helpers.root('src'),
          output: {
            path: helpers.root('dist')
          },

          /**
           * Static analysis linter for TypeScript advanced options configuration
           * Description: An extensible linter for the TypeScript language.
           *
           * See: https://github.com/wbuchwalter/tslint-loader
           */
          tslint: {
            emitErrors: false,
            failOnHint: false,
            resourcePath: 'src'
          }
        }
      })
    ],

    devServer: {
      port: METADATA.port,
      host: METADATA.host,
      historyApiFallback: {
        index: '/index.html'
      },
      watchOptions: {
        aggregateTimeout: 300,
        poll: 1000
      },
      /*
      * Proxy to backend
      */
      proxy: {
        '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8080',
        secure: false
      }
    }
    },

    node: {
      global: true,
      crypto: 'empty',
      process: true,
      module: false,
      clearImmediate: false,
      setImmediate: false
    }

  });
};
```

I already tried to delete `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file, I tested several node version but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

[`import()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import) is asynchronous and returns a promise. Since your package.json has `commonjs` as its type, try using `require('webpack-merge')` instead.